# 'event' is not returning an object representing the document for 'onDocumentDeleted' function in Google Cloud Functions 2nd gen

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a `onDocumentDeleted` Google Cloud Function (2nd gen) but when I delete a document in my application, the event I get is not correct and I can't get the snapshot from it.

My function:

```
import type { QueryDocumentSnapshot } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';
import {
    FirestoreEvent,
    onDocumentDeleted,
} from 'firebase-functions/v2/firestore';

export const myFunction = onDocumentDeleted(
  'myDocuments/{myDocumentID}',
  async (
    event: FirestoreEvent<
      QueryDocumentSnapshot | undefined,
      { myDocumentID: string }
    >,
  ): Promise<void> => {
    console.log('Event is:', JSON.stringify(event));
    const snapshot = event.data as QueryDocumentSnapshot<MyDocument>;
    console.log('Snapshot is:', JSON.stringify(snapshot));
  },
);
```

My deploy script:

```
FUNCTION_NAME=my-function
ENTRY_POINT=myFunction
PROJECT_ID=my-project

gcloud functions deploy ${FUNCTION_NAME} \
--gen2 \
--runtime=nodejs20 \
--region=europe-west3 \
--trigger-location=eur3 \
--source=./deploy \
--entry-point=${ENTRY_POINT} \
--project=${PROJECT_ID} \
--env-vars-file=.env.stage.yaml \
--trigger-event-filters=type=google.cloud.firestore.document.v1.deleted \
--trigger-event-filters=database='(default)' \
--trigger-event-filters-path-pattern=document='myDocuments/{myDocumentID}' \
--allow-unauthenticated \
```

Result:

> Event is: {"0":18,"1":151,"2":232,"3":1,"4":10,"5":60,"6":112,"7":114,"8":111,"9":106,"10":101,"11":99,"12":116,"13":115,"14":47,"15":110,"16":105,"17":114,"18":111,"19":45,"2...

> Snapshot is: undefined

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: What is `onDocumentDeleted`? Please edit the question to show the entire code sample that doesn't work.  We should be able to copy what you have and run it for ourselves.  I don't see that from the examples in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore).

Comment: It's the [Cloud Firestore function trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions-2nd-gen), I have edited the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you're writing is using the Firebase SDK.  It can only be deployed using the Firebase CLI.  You can't use gcloud to deploy functions that use the Firebase SDK.

If you want to deploy a function with gcloud, you must follow the instructions in the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore).  If you want to deploy a function using a Firebase SDK, you must [use the Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=2nd).  Also I think you will do better to follow the Firestore examples on a [different page of Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=2nd).